# configuring reverse proxy https with multiple certificates with Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy

I have the following setup:

- one public IP
- 2 different domain names pointing to the same IP above: domain1.com and domain2.com
- 2 different ssl certificates: one for domain1.com and one for domain2.com
- 2 physical machines on the same LAN (192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.20) running Apache2 and debian 8.5

I tested both servers indipendently forwarding the 443 port traffic to either of the machines. They work nicely.

Now, I am forwarding all port 443 requests arriving to the public IP to the first server at 192.168.1.10 and I would like this server to act as a https server for https://domain1.com and redirect the requests for https://domain2.com to address 192.168.1.20

I have tried to configure a reverse proxy in the first machine. It does redirect the requests for domain2 to the machine at 192.168.1.20 BUT it serves the certificate for domain1.
How can I configure reverse proxy as to present the right certificate for each one of my servers?

thank you in advance.
julia

Comment: the server needs to select the certificate to use based on the SNI extension (Server name indication).  Take a look for SNI support in Apache, it probably supports it.

Comment: Thank you. I did look into SNI but could not make it work. I am kind of a novice with linux :(

Comment: can you post your server block for the proxy machine?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest "solution" (well, workaround) would be to use a single certificate that contains both hostnames. If you cannot do that, then you need to configure Apache SNI, like so: [SSL with Virtual Hosts Using SNI](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI)

Comment: this does not answer my question as all certificates have to be installed in the machine running apache. Thus the trafic from that machine to the other servers on my Lan is no longer https but http.

Comment: Just because you have the certificate for domain2 on the 1st server, the traffic on your LAN will not change, it is still https and it is forwarded to port 443 of the 2nd server.

Answer (score 0):

As some suggested I tried to use the Apache2 reverse proxy.
This somehow works but you have to install all the certificates on the machine running Apache2. Thus the trafic on the lan is no longer https which does not satisfy my requirement.

The solution is to use haproxy. This package can be set up as a pass through for https. There are many examples of such applications on the internet. It does exactly what I am asking for: I can host many https servers on a lan behind a nat router with one single public IP. The trafic is sent by haproxy as https to the indicated server on the LAN. If anyone is interested, I will be glad to share my config file solving precisely the problem I set out in my question.

Comment: Yes, please share, I would like to see how you avoided having the domain2 certificates on the nat router.

Comment: here is my configuration to be added at the end of the default haproxy.cfg file:

Answer (score 0):

To Robert M:
here is my configuration to be added at the end of the default haproxy.cfg file:

```
    frontend ft_https
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    bind *:443

    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }

    acl domain1_com req.ssl_sni -m end  domain1.com # all url ending with domain1.com   
    acl domain2_com req.ssl_sni -i www.domain2.com # exactly www.domain2.com

    use_backend b_domain1_com if domain1_com
    use_backend b_domain2_com if domain2_com
    default_backend b_default

    backend b_default
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    server srv_default 127.0.0.1:1443

    backend b_domain1_com
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    server srv_domain1 192.168.1.10:1443

    backend b_domain2_com
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    server srv_domain2 192.168.1.20:443
```

I had to change the https port for apache on the first server to 1443 because both haproxy and apache cannot bind to the same 443 port as they reside on the same machine, but it is transparent to the user.